# Better Zend Framework introduction?

Tags: php, zend-framework

It's looking more and more like having framework experience is something you've got to have on your CV these days. A lot of job specs I've encountered want people with framework experience, and Zend Framework experience in particular, so I've been looking into learning it.

However, the "quick start" guide on the ZF page is not easy to follow, and I found my eyes were glazing over by the time I was a couple of pages in.

Do you have any recommendations for ZF guides that are a bit easier to follow (and hopefully more interesting to read) than Zend's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Survive the deep end](http://survivethedeepend.com/) very useful and I also read [Zend Framework in action](http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/). If you fancy watching something try [Zend Casts](http://www.zendcasts.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional thoughts and why my eyes where glazing over, too, at first.

I knew php classes, OOP and used classes before. I also heard about the MVC pattern and had a pretty good understanding about it. I never really saw both concepts in full action. ZF is hard core about both!

The documentation and many books do a pretty good job at explaining things but they are most of often very poor at pointing out the differences between Zend Framework classes as stand alone objects and in a MVC concept. Also, they all expect you to have a good understanding already and fail to remind you that you will be lost with that knowledge. I agree that they don't have to teach that but point it out would be nice for newbies.

I basically threw away everything about ZF for a couple weeks and got a grip at OOP and MVC. Once you get the hang of these two the fog begins to lift even with the ZF reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to have a better understanding of OOP concepts, after that try to look at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ and download the pdf this gives you an overview on how MVC works on ZF, the last important thing is to lean how request life cycle works on ZF this video will definitely help http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000bWab-ZF-Grips-a-20111003.flv you need to sign up in order to watch it.

Also Zend Framework 2 beta is out which is not backward compatible with the 1.x version try to look at it also.